# display images in android stored as varbinary in sql

Tags: android, varbinary

i have images stored as varbinary in SQL table, how can display the images in android client

[image: this is how image look like in the table]

Comment: What is the format of the data stored in the `Image` field? Please provide a **complete sample** as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you need to do is

- Convert the `Image` string from DB to a `ByteArray`
- Use `BitmapFactory` in android to convert from `ByteArray` to `Bitmap`
- Set the bitmap of your imageview

  - `val imageText = "FFDD8FFE000104A4694600010101000000000000FFEE1138..."`
  - `myImageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(imageText))`

---

### You could use the following function [kotlin]

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import com.google.android.gms.common.util.Hex

/**
 * Converts a hex string to Bitmap
 *
 * @param image  hex string e.g. "FFD8FFE0..."
 * @return Bitmap
 */
fun getBitmap(image: String): Bitmap {
    // Convert String to ByteArray
    val byteArray = Hex.stringToBytes(image)
    // Convert ByteArray Bitmap
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
}
```

Comment: i get the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64`

Comment: Make sure that you use `FF...` instead of `0xFF..`, If your strings have the header please remove it